# Load combobox with JSP

Tags: jsp, combobox

I have two comboxes. The first is loaded from an SQL database. I want to load the second combobox based on the value in the first one. Here is some of my code:

```
department: <select name="d">
    <%
     while (re.next()) {
        String un = re.getString("nom_dep");
     %>
     <option value="<%= un%>"><%= un%></option>
    <%
    }
     %>
```

Comment: Please state what went wrong. What's the error?

Comment: you can use onchange `<select name="d" onChange="forSecComboFunction()">`

Comment: nothing worng with that code. what is the code in the forSecComboFunction?

Comment: any function that you need to implement

Comment: not helping, i want an exemple of loading a second combobox box from sqk database based on the value of the fisrt combobox